# how to make copy of array instead of reference in java?

Tags: java, arrays, parameter-passing, variable-assignment, pass-by-reference

I want to make an exact copy of given array to some other array but such that even though I change the value of any in the new array it does not change the value in the original array.
I tried the following code but after the third line both the array changes and attains the same value.

```
int [][]a = new int[][]{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};
int[][] b = a;
b[1][0] = 7;
```

instead of the second line I also tried

```
int[][] b = (int[][])a.clone();

int [][] b = new int [3][2];
System.arraycopy(a,0,b,0,a.length);

int [][] b = Arrays.copyOf(a,a.length);
```

None of these helped. Please suggest me an appropriate method. I've tested this piece of code in eclipse scrapbook.

Comment: @Kon Have you looked at his code? :)

Comment: My mistake, read too quickly. Just use loops.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to copy each row of the array; you can't copy the array as a whole.  You may have heard this called deep copying.

Accept that you will need an honest-to-goodness `for` loop.

```
int[][] b = new int[3][];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  b[i] = Arrays.copyOf(a[i], a[i].length);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Louis I found out that Arrays.copy and system.arraycopy work only for 1d array as 2d array is just a 1d array of arrays.

Answer (score -1):

System.arraycopy() should work for you, but it doesn't copy as a whole, it copies "from a specified position to a specified position," according to the java documentation.

Comment: It does not do a deep copy

Comment: @Universitas I tried that but it didn't help.

Comment: @meteors The problem is not the "position" parameters of `System.arraycopy()`, but the fact that it does a shallow copy only, copying only the first level of an n-dimensional array with n > 1. Check out the "duplicate link" from the comments above and the answer from @Louis